# How to check session in Shopify

Tags: session, shopify

How do I check the session for a user which is logged-in?

Once a user has logged in Shopify redirects on `my-shop.myshopify.com/account?sid=`. Maybe I should check `sid`? But how can I achieve this?

I also found `session ID` in cache  - but I didn't find anything helpful in the API.

Such verification is necessary for the `customer` (not Shopify user/admin).

Answer (score 2):

All you can do is get the customer ID client side. That is it. If you succeed at that (the ID is buried in secret cookies that could change at any time), you could do a callback to a private App you install in the store that would securely accept a JS callback with that customer ID. You could use the App and API to look up the customer details and then present the customer with any info you wanted.

Comment: i found session_id in cookie, but this fiend have HttpOnly flag

Comment: Customer ID is here: window.__st.cid